# How can a custom HTML5 menu be created in Video.js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I am presently tinkering with [this](http://www.videojs.com/) HTML5 video player, video.js and I would like to edit the present HTML5 right-click context menu to something of my own. I used  `oncontextmenu="return false"` in the video tag to get rid of the context menu. Any suggestions as to how I go about editing the menu to add what I want link maybe a hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code between script tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.oncontextmenu = function() {
       return false;
    }; 
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/ELcf6/9/)

Comment: @Prashnat: I need your help if your knowledgeable about the subject matter: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096840/how-do-i-embed-a-context-menu-into-an-html5-video-player)