# How do I embed a context menu into an HTML5 video player?

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu, video.js

I am currently fiddling with an HTML5 video player [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/), which I'd like to add this contextual menu [ContextJS](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?76CcN5Nc) to. I am new to this and the more answers I get, I will greatly appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From briefly looking at the ContextJS docs, the first thing you'll want to do is initialize it.

```
// these are all the defaults
context.init({
    fadeSpeed: 100,
    filter: null,
    above: 'auto',
    preventDoubleContext: true,
    compress: false
});
```

Now you can enable the context menu on different items by using `context.attach(selector, menuObjects`).

It appears that `video.js` applies the class `video-js` to all the video player containers it makes. So you can add a context menu to every video on the screen by doing:

```
context.attach('.video-js', [
    {text: 'play', action: function(){ /* code */ }},
    {text: 'help', href: '/help.html'}
]);
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I still have a bit of a problem. Where do you put the two fragments of code above?

Comment: The typical place to put them is inside a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your `<body>`. Make sure they appear after the `video.js` and `ContextJS` scripts.

Comment: I enter these lines before the `</body>` tag in the HTML file.

`<script src="context.js"></script>
script src="video.js"></script>

<script>
    ontext.init({
    fadeSpeed: 100,
    filter: null,
    above: 'auto',
    preventDoubleContext: true,
    compress: false
    });
</script>
<script> 
    context.attach('.video-js', [
    {text: 'play', action: function(){ /* code */ }},
    {text: 'help', href: '/help.html'}
    ]); 
</script>`

Comment: Don't forget that `context.js` needs jQuery to work, as well as special stylesheets. jQuery should be the first script tag, and the style sheets should be put in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, report back if any errors show up in the developer console.

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much @nicklaw It worked. I can't thank you enough. I am now looking at taking some features from two to three other video players and putting it into this one. I'll be sure to contact you in the need of help.

Comment: Here is the thing now. I cannot play/pause the video with the context menu. I use the `{text: 'play', action: function(){
     this.player_.play();
    }},` but have no luck with it.